# Something wrong in interpreting my solution to python challenge?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to find a special character in view-source:http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html

Here is my code:

```
f = open('file.txt')
lines = f.read()
k = ''.join(lines)
stat = ''
for i in k:
    if i in '#&@$!*^{}_()*+[]%':
        stat=stat+''
    else:
        stat=stat+i

print(stat)
```

I'm getting the answer as "equality" but the words are very far apart. why is it so? since I' not adding any space for other characters.

Comment: Looks like Indentation is the problem.

Comment: Python doesn't need to use `;` at the end of lines. Remove those. Also, the page asks you to find the *rare* characters; perhaps you want to count each character and create a histogram?

Comment: Some side notes: Using `f.readlines()` just to join all the lines back together is wasteful and verbose; just use `k = f.read()`. Python doesn't use semicolons as statement terminators like C does; they're separators, so when you write `stat = '';`, you're saying "execute `stat = ''` and then execute an empty statement". The `in` operator makes long tests like that much more readable and faster: `if i in '#&@$!*^{}_()*+[]%'`. Keep your indentation consistent.

Comment: Also, why are you setting `h=6`, a variable you never set to anything else or check anywhere, when the `if` condition is true?

Comment: Also, you've tagged this both python-2.7 and python-3.x. Which one are you using?

Comment: I've updated the code. Still no luck. I'm using 2.7

Comment: And finally, what is this program supposed to do? What it actually does is print out the number of non-special characters in a file. Is that really what they want for 'recognize the characters'? And what does 'I'm getting the answer as "equality" but the words are far apart' mean? You're getting the answer as a number, and there aren't any words anywhere.

Comment: If you'll run it in the compiler there a word "equality" will be displayed. Since these are the 8 rare characters in that file.

Comment: First, you still haven't removed the unnecessary `join`. Again, just `k = f.read()`. Second, after your edits, I still have no idea what your program is supposed to do, or what it's doing instead that you don't like.

Comment: The source of the file is the link I just pasted.

Comment: 'these are the 8 rare characters in the file'… which 'these'? The 17 characters in your program?

Comment: "e" "q" "u" "a" "l" "i" "t" "y" are the rare characters. Anyway, I got the solution someone wrote below. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not skipping the newlines in the file:

```
for i in k:
    if i not in '#&@$!*^{}_()*+[]%\n':
        stat=stat+i
```

Note that there is little point in appending an empty string for anything in your special characters string. Only append when the character is **not** in that string.

You already found the solution anyway, but the challenge could have been better met with actually finding the rare characters:

```
from collections import Counter
import requests  # external library but much more convenient than urllib2

r = requests.get('http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html')
text = r.text.rsplit('<!--', 1)[-1].rsplit('-->', 1)[0]  # extract comment
counts = Counter(text)
rare = {c for c in counts if counts[c] < 5}
print ''.join([c for c in text if c in rare])
```

where *rare* turns out to be *only once*, really.

Answer (score 0):

You're not skipping linebreaks, which is why you get a sort of "stretched" output.

Here's my attempt at solving it, incorporating the comments to your question:

```
f = open('file.txt')
data = f.read()
stat = ''
for i in data:
    if i in '#&@$!*^{}_()+[]%]\n':
        h=6
    else:
        stat=stat+i
print stat
```